# How To get all latitude and longitude from source to destination place on selection of suggested routes

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dictionary

i want to fetch all the latitude and longitude between origin place to destination place.

For that i have written following script but it will not give me the latitude and longitude between those two place.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        var directionDisplay;
        var directionsRenderer;
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        var map;

        function drawMap(midpoint) {
            var mid = midpoint.split(",");
            var start = new google.maps.LatLng(mid[0], mid[1]);
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 7,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                center: start,
                mapTypeControl: false
            }
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

            var input = (document.getElementById('origin'));

            var inputdestination = (document.getElementById('destination'));

            var types = document.getElementById('changetype-all');
            map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
            map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(types);

            var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
            autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

            var autocompletedestination = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(inputdestination);
            autocompletedestination.bindTo('bounds', map);
        }

        function getRendererOptions(main_route) {
            if (main_route) {
                var _colour = '#00458E';
                var _strokeWeight = 4;
                var _strokeOpacity = 1.0;
                var _suppressMarkers = false;
            }
            else {
                var _colour = '#ED1C24';
                var _strokeWeight = 2;
                var _strokeOpacity = 0.7;
                var _suppressMarkers = false;
            }

            var polylineOptions = { strokeColor: _colour, strokeWeight: _strokeWeight, strokeOpacity: _strokeOpacity };

            var rendererOptions = { draggable: true, suppressMarkers: _suppressMarkers, polylineOptions: polylineOptions };

            return rendererOptions;
        }

        function renderDirections(result, rendererOptions, routeToDisplay) {


            if (routeToDisplay == 0) {
                var _colour = '#00458E';
                var _strokeWeight = 4;
                var _strokeOpacity = 1.0;
                var _suppressMarkers = false;
            }
            else {
                var _colour = '#ED1C24';
                var _strokeWeight = 4;
                var _strokeOpacity = 0.7;
                var _suppressMarkers = false;
            }

            // if (routeToDisplay == 0) _colour = "#FF0000";


            // create new renderer object
            var directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
                draggable: true,
                suppressMarkers: _suppressMarkers,
                polylineOptions: {
                    strokeColor: _colour,
                    strokeWeight: _strokeWeight,
                    strokeOpacity: _strokeOpacity
                }
            });
            directionsRenderer.setMap(map);
            directionsRenderer.setPanel(document.getElementById('directions_panel'));
            directionsRenderer.setDirections(result);
            directionsRenderer.setRouteIndex(routeToDisplay);

            directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
```

Below if condition is used for get all latitude and longitude between two places but it is not wokrs.

```
                    if (response.routes && response.routes.length > 0) {
                        var routes = response.routes;
                        for (var j = 0; j < routes.length; j++) {
                            var points = routes[j].overview_path;
                            var ul = document.getElementById("vertex");
                            for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
                                var li = document.createElement('li');
                                li.innerHTML = getLiText(points[i]);
                                ul.appendChild(li);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        function getLiText(point) {
            var lat = point.lat(),
                lng = point.lng();
            return "lat: " + lat + " lng: " + lng;
        }
        function requestDirections(start, end, routeToDisplay, main_route) {

            var request = {
                origin: start,
                destination: end,
                travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
                provideRouteAlternatives: main_route
            };


            directionsService.route(request, function (result, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    if (main_route) {
                        var rendererOptions = getRendererOptions(true);
                        for (var i = 0; i < result.routes.length; i++) {
                            renderDirections(result, rendererOptions, i);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        var rendererOptions = getRendererOptions(false);
                        renderDirections(result, rendererOptions, routeToDisplay);

                    }
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Below is the body:

```
<body>
    <div id="vertex-container">
        <label>Points</label>
        <ul id="vertex">
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div>
    //...all the other input and button
    //....
</body>
```

From above script i can get all the route from origin place to destination place but i didnt get the `all latitude and longitude` between those place.

[image]

you can see that i can get suggested route between two place.

But now i want to print all latitude and longitude between those route which i am selecting.

Suppose here 3 routes are there .

`now suppose i am selecting 1st then it will fetch all the latitude and longitude between those places only for that route`

```
Now suppose i am slecting 2nd suggested route then it will display all latitude and longitude between that route
```

so now ,

```
how can i get all the latitude and longitude between those places for selected route from suggested routes?
```

Comment: That means :- latitude and longitude

Comment: what do  you mean by "all"?

Comment: all means each and every latitude and longitude details between those two places on selected route

Comment: let's assume there is be a infinite number of points on a line...

Comment: ya exactly..but i want that each and every..

Comment: you want to get a infinite number of something? Impossible with a computer!

Comment: look at my JavaScript i have mentioned if condition from that i can fetch ..

Comment: You want to get lat and lng from all steps of the directions? What you see in your yellow sidebar?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @MrUpsidown yes i want all. In yellow side bar i can see only the route details.

Comment: Are you trying do do something like is done on [this page](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_directions_custom_iconsC.html) (extract all the points to recreate the route polyline)?

Comment: [Perhaps a better example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_directions-draggable2Xml.html?addr1=New%20Dehli,Dehli,%20India&addr2=Yamuna%20Nagar,%20Haryana,%20India)

Comment: @geocodezip Thanks but in this example it is display only 1 route     from origin to destination place.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: i mean that in this example it is showing only 1 route from origin to destination . it is `not showing` suggested route(multiple route for origin to source place)

Comment: @deepak yes you are right. i want multiple route from source to destination place.

Comment: @geocodezip this example shows only 1 route . it is not showing suggested route.

Comment: Check my `image` in question . Right side it is showing suggested route.

Comment: Where in your question does it ask about alternate routes?  Or is that what you are trying to ask when you say "all the latitude and longitude between origin place to destination place"?  [Example with alternate routes](http://www.geocodezip.com/differentum_com_map-testA.html)

Comment: All latitude and longitude between origin to destination but with multiple routes. so when i select any route from suggested route then it will fetch only that route's all latitude and longitude.

Comment: i had written in last line that `how can i get all the latitude and longitude between those places for selected route?` now i have change and clarify like `how can i get all the latitude and longitude between those places for selected route from suggested routes?`

Answer (score 2):

You have to loop through the alternate routes and for each route loop through all steps.

Here is an example that shows how to draw all the alternate routes to the map and place a marker at each step. I have used different colors so you can clearly identify each route.

Note that it uses the `start_location` of each step. We don't know if that is what you need.

```
var directionDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;

function initialize() {

    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 7,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        center: center
    }

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

    var start = "Yamuna Nagar, Haryana, India";
    var end = "New Delhi, India";
    var method = 'DRIVING';
    var request = {
        origin: start,
        destination: end,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode[method],
        provideRouteAlternatives: true
    };

    directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {

        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

            var routesSteps = [];
            var routes = response.routes;
            var colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'orange', 'yellow', 'black'];

            for (var i = 0; i < routes.length; i++) {

                new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
                    map: map,
                    directions: response,
                    routeIndex: i,
                    polylineOptions: {

                        strokeColor: colors[i],
                        strokeWeight: 4,
                        strokeOpacity: .3
                    }
                });

                var steps = routes[i].legs[0].steps;
                var stepsCoords = [];

                for (var j = 0; j < steps.length; j++) {

                    stepsCoords[j] = new google.maps.LatLng(steps[j].start_location.lat(), steps[j].start_location.lng());

                    new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: stepsCoords[j],
                        map: map,
                        icon: {
                            path: 'M-20,0a20,20 0 1,0 40,0a20,20 0 1,0 -40,0',
                            scale: .5,
                            fillColor: colors[i],
                            fillOpacity: .3,
                            strokeWeight: 0
                        },
                        title: steps[j].maneuver
                    });
                }

                routesSteps[i] = stepsCoords;
            }

            // Here is your array of routes steps coordinates
            console.log('routesSteps', routesSteps);
        }
    });
}

initialize();
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/3uLqrd7c/)</kbd>

Comment: No This is not what i want.. please see this example [link](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_directions-draggable2Xml.html?addr1=New%20Dehli,Dehli,%20India&addr2=Yamuna%20Nagar,%20Haryana,%20India)

Comment: and also check my `image` in question .

Comment: You obviously need to give more info. The given link gives all steps coordinates for one route. My answer gives all steps coordinates for all routes. Now what do you need??

Comment: i need option for selecting routes and get all the latitude and longitude of that selected routes.

Comment: You have an example of how to retrive the points for 1 route and for all routes. Can't you adapt this to your needs?

Comment: i can't. That's why i have put this question. i am unable to fetch all lat and lon on selection of "suggested route".

Comment: Did you try **anything** from the given suggestions?

Comment: yes i had tried. but i didn't my answer.

Comment: This answer is very useful...
it show all route prediction between two place...